# "You are commenting on another answer" warning doesn't go away on discard

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

If you scroll while commenting on an answer and then discard the comment, the (very large, very red) warning text won't revert to the add comment button unless it's scrolled out of view.

[image: in-progress comment warning]

Comment: I could probably do without that warning to begin with too, at least in the case where I hadn't actually started writing a comment on another post. But that's a bit separate from this bug report.

Comment: I'm looking into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that we were not refreshing the cells of other answers that were visible while a user discards the comment. This was easy to miss since most answers are a little bit longer, meaning that, in the most common case, they would be automatically refresh by UIKit before coming onto the screen.

In order to reproduce, you could start drafting a comment, then scroll away to another answer (where you see the "You are commenting on another answer" and then discard.

This issue has been resolved. The fix will be available tonight's build.